# Generate pages with Flask without using separate template files

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to keep things minimal, so I don't want to create templates, directory structures, etc.  I have a simple CSS file available on the web (via [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/)) and I want to use it to style the page generated by a view.  How can I render a page without templates?

```
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)

# <insert magic here>
# application.get_and_use_my_super_cool_CSS_file(URL)
# <insert magic here>

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "hello world"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host = "0.0.0.0")
```

Comment: What is your aversion to templates? To do this, you would have to write out your HTML (including the CSS) as your return string of `hello()`. Or you can just use `render_template`...

Comment: If you don't want to create a template file, you'll need to build the HTML inside your application code. You'll need to reference your stylesheet inside that. This is generally harder to both read and maintain than using a template file.

Comment: I have upvoted this question. The reason I left Django to transition to flask is because of the complete minimalism idealism. We should be given the option to not use templates or anything else that we don't need. If we want to quickly prototype something, sometimes a single file that contains everything is all we need, and at the very least it serves as a valuable learning exercise. Later, if we expand our project, then we may wish to use templates or something else entirely such as Django.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to write templates as separate files, you can use [`render_template_string`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.render_template_string) instead.  This is typically not a very useful feature, as it becomes difficult to maintain large templates written as Python strings.  Flask's Jinja env also provides some extra help when rendering files it recognizes, such as turning on autoescape for HTML files, so you need to be more careful when rendering from strings directly.

```
return render_template_string('''<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css url"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, World!</p>
    </body>
</html>
'''
```